# Integrate $\int \frac {dx} {x^{27}\left( x^{7}-6\right) }$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

I tried to split it as 
$$\int\frac{1}{x^{34}}\frac{dx}{\left(1-\frac{6}{x^{7}}\right)}.$$

Okay so the question is incorrect but B is the correct answer as per the key , can anyone backderive

Comment: We use dollar signs to mark $\LaTeX$.  I put some in your post and it worked fine. I also tried to put them in the title, but it didn't work right.  Please check.  @mickep edited the title successfully.

Comment: Thabk you soo much , will remember to put $ for sure next time

Comment: I guess the result of this one will be terrible. Are you sure you wrote the integral correctly? Is this an exercise, or what is the source? What you, in principle, can do is to do partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: @mickep:  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Fx%5E27%2F%28x%5E7-6%29) gets a mess, supporting your thought, but there could be some magic cancellation

Comment: I tried proceeding via taking $x^7$ common but not able to proceed , i also tried multiplying and dividing with $x^5$ but getting stuck .

Comment: @RossMillikan of course , our professor told us that the answer is just two steps with the right substitution

Comment: Are you sure it is not $\int\frac{x^{27}}{x^7-6}\,dx$, because that will evaluate quickly with $t=x^7$.

Comment: @mickep lol yes I'm pretty sure its not like that .

Comment: If option b is the answer can anyone back-derive the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observe that $$\frac{1}{x^{27}(x^7-a)} = x \cdot \frac{1}{u^4(u-a)},$$ where $u = x^7$, which facilitates a much easier decomposition via $u$:  $$\frac{1}{x^{27}(x^7-a)} = \frac{x}{a^4(x^7-a)} - \frac{1}{a^4 x^6} - \frac{1}{a^3 x^{13}} - \frac{1}{a^2 x^{20}} - \frac{1}{a x^{27}}.$$  All but the first term have easy antiderivatives.  The first term can be integrated by further decomposition, via the identity $$z^7 - 1 = (z-1)\prod_{k=1}^3 (z - \zeta_7^k)(z - \zeta_7^{-k}) = (z-1)\prod_{k=1}^3 \left( z^2 - 2 \cos \tfrac{2\pi k}{7} + 1 \right),$$ resulting in a product of linear and quadratic terms.  I am not going to bother to complete the computation or integration:  it is tedious and not illuminating.

---

Based on the picture you provided of the question, I have determined that there is a typographical error, and the integrand was intended to be $$\frac{1}{x^{22}(x^7-6)}.$$  It is only this particular exponent that will lead to an antiderivative that has anything remotely resembling the form that is claimed, for suitable constants or functions $A$, $B$, as then, the partial fraction decomposition will admit an obvious choice of substitution.  If we backsolve by assuming $A$ is a scalar and $B = B(x)$ is a function of $x$, differentiating the RHS with respect to $x$ immediately yields $$\frac{1}{x^?(x^7-6)} = A B'(x)\left(\frac{1}{B(x)} - 18 + 18B(x) - 6B(x)^2\right).$$  Thus if the RHS is to be a rational function, $B(x)$ must itself be a rational function.  If we substitute in the various choices, however, none fits.  This is because the form of the antiderivative is itself flawed:  the exponent in the integrand is not the only typographical error.  Whomever wrote the question intended the answer to be (B), but the polynomial in $B$ is not correct.

Comment: That is a nice partial fraction decomposition! I wonder if this is not the best it can be, but who knows, maybe someone show up with a magical substitution...

Comment: Very well done!  +1

Comment: I will try with your substation and thanks for the answer .

Comment: But the problem is that we cant land on any of the options

Comment: @SujithZis, no, the problem is that you posted a TINY PICTURE of a flawed problem, and if you want help--which I have gone above and beyond what is reasonable to provide by trying to decipher the intended question--then you will need to be less demanding and more accommodating by providing a clear image or text of the actual question and your attempts to solve it.

Comment: Indeed, there is probably a typo in the exercise.

Comment: Im so sorry i was being rude , i have reuploaded the image , your efforts to answer are all very well appreciated

Comment: @heropup so much respect man, yes the question was wrong wolfram alpha proves it all , I've also been trying to figure out the correct question since past 2hrs by back-deriving from the options as you told , anyway thanks